# Mysql query to extract tld from dns domain names

Tags: mysql, dns

In this practice, I'd like to extarct the domain name from the TLD (Top Level Domain) given the following tables.

```
Table name: dns
+---------------------------+
| dnsdomain                 |
+---------------------------+
| ns2.hosting.indo.net.id.  |
| ns1.onepanel.indo.net.id. |
| ns-1591.awsdns-06.co.uk.  |
| mail189.atl21.rsgsv.net.  |
| gli.websitewelcome.com.   |
| ns2.metrolink.pl.         |
| ns1.metrolink.pl.         |
| ns-1591.awsdns-06.co.uk.  |
| NS3.METRORED.HN.          |
| NS.METRORED.HN.           |
| ns2.hosting.indo.net.id.  |
| ns1.onepanel.indo.net.id. |
| www.csis.ul.ie.           |
+---------------------------+
and 
Table name: tld
+----------+
| tld      |
+----------+
| .net.id. |
| .co.uk.  |
| .net.    |
| .com.    |
| .pl.     |
| .uk.     |
| .hn.     |
| .id.     |
| .ie.     |
+----------+
```

I'd like to print out the dnstomain with its related tld. I perform the following mysql query:

```
select test.dnsdomain , tld.tld from test join tld where locate(tld.tld, test.dnsdomain, length(test.dnsdomain) - length (tld.tld) )!= 0;
```

and get the below table:

```
+---------------------------+----------+
| dnsdomain                 | tld      |
+---------------------------+----------+
| ns2.hosting.indo.net.id.  | .net.id. |
| ns1.onepanel.indo.net.id. | .net.id. |
| ns-1591.awsdns-06.co.uk.  | .co.uk.  |
| mail189.atl21.rsgsv.net.  | .net.    |
| gli.websitewelcome.com.   | .com.    |
| ns2.metrolink.pl.         | .pl.     |
| ns1.metrolink.pl.         | .pl.     |
| ns-1591.awsdns-06.co.uk.  | .uk.     |
| NS3.METRORED.HN.          | .hn.     |
| NS.METRORED.HN.           | .hn.     |
| ns2.hosting.indo.net.id.  | .id.     |
| ns1.onepanel.indo.net.id. | .id.     |
| www.csis.ul.ie.           | .ie.     |
+---------------------------+----------+
```

The problem with my query is that for every single record in table 'test' it does not check all the tld from table 'tld' that's why I see something like:

```
| ns-1591.awsdns-06.co.uk.  | .uk.     |
```

where as the expected result would be like:

```
| ns-1591.awsdns-06.co.uk.  | .co.uk.  |
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick edit. The correct name for first table is 'test'. I mistakenly put 'dns'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Group By` function. This statement works in **mysql** :

```
select test.dnsdomain , tld.tld ,
max(length(tld.tld)) as x
from test 
join tld 
where locate(tld.tld, test.dnsdomain, length(test.dnsdomain) - length (tld.tld) )!= 0; 
group by test.tnsdomain
```

OR

```
 select test.dnsdomain , max(tld.tld) as tld
    from test 
    join tld 
    where locate(tld.tld, test.dnsdomain, length(test.dnsdomain) - length (tld.tld) )!= 0; 
    group by test.tnsdomain
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. That dnsname `'blah.co.uk.'` matches both `'.co.uk.'` and `'.uk.'`. Both rows are being returned.

Sounds like you want to filter out all but the "longest" matching `tld`.

NOTE: I'd prefer to use the `RIGHT()` function to extract the rightmost portion from `dnsdomain`. (That's just easier for me to understand, but it should be equivalent to the expression you are using.)

Reference: [**`RIGHT()`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

One option to filter out the shorter matches is to use a correlated subquery to determine the *maximum* length of all of the `tld` that match, and only return the `tld` that has that length.

For example:

```
SELECT test.dnsdomain
     , tld.tld
  FROM test
  JOIN tld 
    ON tld.tld = RIGHT(test.tndsdomain,CHAR_LENGTH(tld.tld))
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(tld.tld) = 
       ( SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(m.tld))
           FROM tld m
          WHERE m.tld = RIGHT(test.tndsdomain,CHAR_LENGTH(m.tld))
       )
```

You could get an equivalent result using a `JOIN` operation to an inline view, it does basically the same thing:

```
SELECT test.dnsdomain
     , tld.tld
  FROM test
  JOIN tld 
    ON tld.tld = RIGHT(test.tndsdomain,CHAR_LENGTH(tld.tld))
  JOIN ( SELECT n.dnsdomain
              , MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(m.tld)) AS tld_len 
           FROM test n
           JOIN tld m 
             ON m.tld = RIGHT(n.tndsdomain,CHAR_LENGTH(m.tld))
          GROUP BY n.dnsdomain
       ) o
    ON o.dnsdomain = test.dnsdomain
   AND o.tld_len = CHAR_LENGTH(tld.tld)
```

---

Also, it's better practice to use **`CHAR_LENGTH()`** function than **`LENGTH()`** function.  The `LENGTH()` function returns a number of bytes, which is the same as the number of characters, for single byte character sets (like `latin1`), but with multibyte charactersets, the number of characters can be less than the number of bytes.)

Comment: I've made some changes to the first query (some typos were corrected):     SELECT test.dnsdomain
     , tld.tld
  FROM test
  JOIN tld 
    ON tld.tld = RIGHT(test.dnsdomain,CHAR_LENGTH(tld.tld))
  JOIN ( SELECT n.dnsdomain
              , MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(m.tld)) AS tld_len 
           FROM test n
           JOIN tld m 
             ON m.tld = RIGHT(n.dnsdomain,CHAR_LENGTH(m.tld))
          GROUP BY n.dnsdomain
       ) o
    ON o.dnsdomain = test.dnsdomain
   AND o.tld_len = CHAR_LENGTH(tld.tld);